# TeamCity to Gitlab-CI : Multiple Build Configurations

Tags: teamcity, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two projects in TeamCity, both of them are configured with 4 build configuration. Now, we are moving to GitLab-CI.

Can I have multiple "Build Configurations" in GitLab-CI, just as TeamCity?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "build configurations"? I'm not familiar with the term, I assume it's from TeamCity?

Comment: Yes, Build Configuration is a "TeamCity" term.
After creating a project in TC in the "Build Configuration" section user can add multiple build configuration, eg, it could be a Debug Build or a Release Build!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, what you'd want to do is create different "jobs" in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that run depending on the branch they're run on (or some other variable, however you determine which build configuration you're wanting to run). See the docs for the yml file: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/README.html#creating-a-gitlab-ci-yml-file